# Why protect "general factor"s in factor analysis?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, interpretation, factor-analysis, factor-rotation

My Multivariate Analysis textbook states that

> As we have noted, a general factor (that is, one on which all the
>   variables load highly) tends to be "destroyed after rotation." For
>   this reason, in cases where a general factor is evident, an orthogonal
>   rotation is sometimes performed with the general factor loadings
>   fixed.

This confuses me. As far as I know, the point of (varimax) factor rotation is to maximize the variance of the square of the loadings on each factor, and a "general factor" doesn't contribute a lot of variances, so it *should* be broken down.

Why do we protect these general factors?

Comment: This is a good question, but the topic itself is a bit nonstatistical, and sooner a philosophical. Should we respect and keep or should we disregard and destroy a g-factor? There can be many opinions, contrasting, and it also depends in the aims and the domain of the study. Your textbook probably says this: if m factors were extracted and we wish to keep the 1st factor loadings (usually it is the g one) as they are, just perform rotation of the subspace of the m-1 subsequent factors.

Comment: Another option would be to use quartimax rotation which spares the g-factor to an extent.

Comment: See an example in a little manuscript of mine http://go.helms-net.de/stat/fa/FullComponentsFA_1.htm , example 4. There I extracted a general factor ("age") because of its general importance. Then in rest of the variation I do a pca to find the partial principal components and find 2 interesting ones, following by a varimax-rotation on the 2 partial PC's detecting two groups of items each having a common property. The used dataset was synthetic and only "painted" to agree with our studies, but the page was only for discussion of the ***methods***, so the modelling might be somehow innatural...